# SQL Identity Specification is out of order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the identity specification set on the "EventID" Column. It has been working great for quite a few years.

The other day I noticed the internal website was wrong so I went to the DB and the column is out of order. It goes from 21,22,25,24,26. There is very little to no information in entry# 25. The specification is set to "Yes", Is Identity is set to Yes, Identity Increment is 1 and Identity Seed is 1.I have attempted to delete the wrong entry but it will not let me delete it.

How do I fix this? Remove the specification? Re-create the table? It has been a while since I have been actively working n SQL. Suggestions please and thank you!

Comment: You don't. It is a completely synthetic value and there is no promise that any value will not somehow be skipped. There are many reasons for this to occur. Short answer - just live with it. If you need a longer explanation just search "sql server gaps in identity column"

Comment: I can live with it since it does not seem to be causing any other tables to error. The problem is I am seeing added information on the website that should not be there. So I am trying to remove the row that is causing the problem. Thanks

Comment: FYI, The `INT` datatype can only contain numbers between -2^31 (-2 147 483 648) to 2^31-1 (2 147 483 647).  So if it goes from `2 122 252 426` then maybe it should become BIGINT? (btw, that's seems like a huge table, or there's some process that constantly deletes and re-inserts the same records)

Comment: @LukStorms - I think you have misread the question. the largest number mentioned is 26

Comment: Oh right, it's just a few numbers, not 1 big one. Doh!  Totally misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

What could you possibly mean by "the column is out of order"? SQL tables represent *unordered* sets. The only ordering is provided by data in (other) columns in the row.

The `identity` column in SQL Server captures the insertion order of the data. By definition, it cannot be out-of-order with the insertion order (well, we might disagree on the ordering of two insertions that happen "at the same time", but I don't think that is the gist of your question).

Note: This assumes that `identity` has not bee overridden. It is, of course, possible to allow someone to specify an identity value, allowing gaps and "out-of-order" values. Your question suggests that this is not happening either.

Comment: The Identity column has always ordered correctly when new data is entered for the current year.The only time there are gaps in the order are when a row is removed  but it always stays in sequence when the next row is added. This time as you can see in the original question rows 24 & 25 are out of order. I have not seen this before and am not sure how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @DuaneW, how do you know the identify values were inserted out of order? If you didn't query the table with `ORDER BY`, data may be returned in any arbitrary order. Gaps are normal and expected.

Comment: Dan, When I go to the table I can see all the data entered in the rows. The first Column is the EventID column and it is set to Identity Specification and I can see the order of the rows in sequence. 1,2,3,4...etc. When it gets to row 24 & 25 they are backwards. 22,25,24, 26. The 24th row is out of order. I have not seen that before. Thanks

Comment: @DuaneW, a table is an unordered set of rows so the order in which they appear is not deterministic unless you specify `ORDER BY`. In practice, rows are often returned in same order as inserted or clustered index order without order by but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

What Gordon Linoff above is getting at is that there is *no* natural order to an SQL table.  Client tools will show you the data in a particular order, but the table itself has no order (outside the physical order of storage, not relevant to this problem).  If you don't specify an ORDER BY, you'll get the data in some arbitrary order.  I can't remember how SQL decides on that order, because no-one ever relies on it.

Your IDENTITY column must be "out of order" relative to some other ordering: this is just the order you're *viewing* the data in (perhaps ORDER BY SomeDateEnteredColumn?).

The IDENTITY value being relatively out of order shouldn't matter at all.  If an application relies on it to express a newer-older relation between rows, that's a bad idea.

If you can't delete the row with ID=25, it's probably because of a foreign key: a related row in another table connects to this row.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I build internal websites and link them to databases on the backside to collect the information entered on the website. In this case I ended up renaming the original table in the db and created a new table with the same name and columns. This seems to have fixed the issue. The information on the website is correct and the information in the table is also correct. Thanks again!!